# Garena Plus on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows

Does the current version of Garena Plus run in Ubuntu 12.04 without problems? I've tried Wine, but it doesn't work, and I can't find any news about it on WineHQ. I followed the instructions on [their forums](http://forum.hon.garena.com/showthread.php?2679-HoN-on-Linux-working!-%28maybe-Mac-also-can-use-%29), but it still didn't work. Is there any application that can run Windows programs on Ubuntu 12.04 except Wine?

Comment: What errors do you actually get when running it with Wine?

Comment: I can't remember clearly but I think it was like about a dll file. I'm at work right now so I can't try running it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**play-on-linux**](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) . It's similar to wine. see the link for more info

Answer (score 0):

Your other options involve:

```
http://codeweavers.com/
http://cedega.com/
```

or any virtual machine manager like virtualbox

```
http://www.virtualbox.org/
```